# Is it possible to set .edmx models output directory to other project in solution?

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4.1, asp.net-mvc-4, .net-4.5

I need to have my .edmx file in my Data project and its generated models in my Data.Model project.
Is it possible? And if so, how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you using the EF DbContext Generator to generate code-first models? If so, you can build your `.edmx` file the same way you always do. Once it is created and the models are generated, move the MyContext.tt template into your Data.Models project (Leave your `MyContext.Context.tt` file in the project with your `.edmx`).

After that, open up the `Context.tt` and near the top change the inputFile to the relative path of your Data.Model project. It will end up something like:

> string inputFile = @"../MyProject.Data.Model/MyDataModel.edmx";

Go back to your `MyContext.Context.tt` in your .Data project and change the CustomToolNamespace property to **Data.Model**

From then on, when you make changes to your `.edmx` file,  you will have to also go into your Data.Model project and save the `MyContext.tt` again to regenerate the models.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works, but it looks like a hack in case I have to save the MyContext.tt. If there is another way to make this work, even thought I should use another generator (Not EF DbContext one), I would really like to hear that one out :)

Comment: A year later and this has REALLY helped me! Just wanted to say that I was able to actually change the inputFile string in the ORIGINAL Context.tt file to make it a relative path from the solution (@"../MyProject.Data/MyDataModel.edmx") and then add the .tt file as a link in another project. This isn't what the original poster was asking for but it has meant I don't have to keep saving it again and again.